# Problem Linking Shared Object

Tags: java, android, shared-objects

I have a shared object file which I call from my android app. Until now I had it in my java project, and I loaded it like that:

```
static { System.loadLibrary("mysofile") };
```

Now I'm trying to load it from other location:

```
static {System.loadLibrary("/mnt/sdcard/mysofile.so"}
```

But I get the following error:

```
03-13 14:26:12.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2339): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_segments[928]: 92 failed to map segment from 'mysofile.so' @ 0x83400000 (0x00001488). p_vaddr=0x00000000 p_offset=0x00000000
```

Could someone help me solve it?

Thanks,
Binyamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want most likely is not supported. Please use the NDK and follow its instructions for properly supporting JNI on Android.

Also, never hard-code `/mnt/sdcard`, as that is wrong on most Android devices. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to identify the root of external storage.

Comment: Thanks. I used the NDK for basic use, but I'm trying to download and replace libraries on-the-fly (for test purposes) so I tried to use library from outside my application folder. 
Regarding hard-coded paths - I absolutely agree, this is just part of a test code.